# Building a 3D modeling and importing workflow of a 3D indie game model

Tags: textures, blender, godot, 3d-modeling, material

So, I am considering building an "SOP" for an indie game.
The question might be simple, dumb, and wide but not deep. I am using Blender and Godot to build 3D character and environment models. These two software have their own material systems. Which one should I use to create the game model appearance?

Comment: There are several questions interleaved here. One is "what software should I use to make the model" one is "what software should I use to make its textures", then there's "what software should I use to make its materials" and "how do I import these things into Godot". Can you clarify exactly which part you need help with? We don't give software recommendations here, but we can help you overcome a specific problem in your asset creation/import workflow.

Comment: okay, Cause i have found these two have their own material system. I have no idea which one to utilize.

Comment: That depends on what you want to use it *for*. Eg. whether you're trying to use procedural techniques or 3D painting to author texture maps, or if you're trying to set up the shaders that will render your object every frame in real time as your game runs. Try editing your question to clarify.

Comment: That is the answer, thanks XD

Answer (score 2):

*Part of the philosophy of Godot is to build a free software ecosystem, and yes, that includes compatibility with Blender, and also with open standards.*

---

**Making games or video**

I'll assume that you are going to use Godot, since this is for indie games.

For movies, you would not need Godot, since Blender can render video. However, I also want to mention that Godot 4 has a Movie Maker Mode, which allows you to record high quality game play footage for your game trailers without the need of screen capture, and without worry of framing problems.

---

**Godot vs Blender**

The tooling for modeling in Godot (without third party plugins) is very limited. In fact, Godot is not trying to replace Blender.

Because of that I would encourage to use Blender for modeling. And that would also be the answer for all the other things Godot does not do (without third party plugins): texture painting, sculpting, retopology…

---

Now, creating simple models in Godot can be useful. On one hand, if the model is very simple it might not be worth bothering the Blender expert with it if we can quickly do it in Godot.

On the other hand, you might find useful to prototype scenarios in Godot, then export them into GLTF (You find the option in Project -> Tools)… Which you can then import into Blender to improve them, and then import back to Godot.

---

I would also like to encourage to take advantage of Godot to automate your process. For example, you can use a `tool` script to convert `CSG` nodes into `MeshInstances` which should give you no trouble when exporting to GTLF. Similarly, you might use `tool` scripts to do procedural generation, which you can then export to GLTF. *Yes, you could also do procedural stuff in blender.*

*By the way, Godot can unwrap and view UVs (of `ArrayMesh`)… That will likely NOT be part of the workflow. Another thing that Godot does is Create Outline Meshes (the option creates an slightly larger inverted `ArrayMesh` - useful for an outline effect). Thus, if you ever need to unwrap UVs - in Godot - of something that is not an `ArrayMesh`, you can create their outline, and then the outline of the outline. Which will result in an `ArrayMesh` otherwise identical to the original.*

---

**Basic import workflow**

In Godot the imported model will be an scene. The approach Godot recommends is to make an scene that inherits from the imported model, and do Godot specific modification there…

However, I'll recommend composition instead. I mean: create an scene dedicated to contain the imported model (an scene containing another scene). So in this other scene you can add modifications on top of the  imported model, that will not be lost if you need to re-import it.

The modification you might want to do on Godot include: adding an `AnimationTree`, setting material overrides, adding bone attachments, setting up inverse kinematics, making the root a physics body and adding physics colliders, and so on.

---

**Blender to Godot 3.x**

Godot 3.x has fairly good support for importing GLB and GTLF (which are open standards). And, of course, you can export from Blender.

So, if you can export to GLB or GLTF from Blender, and the model keeps the materials, you are going to get a good representation of the materials in Godot 3.x. *You might still have to tweak it, in particular increase roughness or lower specularity.*

However, if the materials you want to create cannot be exported to GLB or GLTF (i.e. they are a complex shader graph), then you are better off creating the materials in Godot. However, you still want to assign placeholder materials in Blender because Godot lacks the tooling to define which surfaces will have each material.

*Godot uses "import hints" which are suffixes you add in the name of the elements of the model to tell Godot how to handle them. See [import hints](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/assets_pipeline/importing_scenes.html#import-hints).*

See [Importing Scenes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/assets_pipeline/importing_scenes.html)

---

**Blender to Godot 4.x**

For  Godot 4 the support for GLB and GTLF has been improved. You will get a better representation of the materials. And you will have better control of how they are imported with a new UI that lets you specify how to handle different parts of the model.

You also get FBX support (which has been the de-facto standard for the industry, despite being a proprietary format) via FBX2glTF※. However, it might not be the best option because it is even more restrictive on which materials it supports. You will find that the materials are lost in FBX unless you set the shader graph in Blender in a very specific way (just a Base Color, a Principal BSDF and a Material Output). *And also it is a proprietary format.*

※: You need to download FBX2glTF separately, and configure the path in Editor Settings -> General -> File System -> Import.*

But that is not all. Godot 4 can interface with Blender※. So you can add blend files in your Godot project and have Godot communicate with Blender to get the information it needs to import them. Which also means that modifying the blend file will make Godot re-import the model without having an intermediary file.

※: You need to download Blender separately, and configure the path in Editor Settings -> General -> File System -> Import.*

*Yes, the import hints system still works in Godot 4.*

See [Importing Scenes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.0/tutorials/assets_pipeline/importing_scenes.html).

---

**On other tools**

My Blender skills are very limited. So I'll tell you some workarounds somebody like me can use when working alone or in a team that lacks somebody with Blender expertise. *Hopefully you find something useful here.*

First of all, if you can find another software that exports to GLTF or GLB you can import that into Godot (for example, for architecture, I have used an old version of SketchUp - for desktop - with a community plugin to export to GLTF)… But even if you can't, you might use Blender to convert the models.

And for characters… VRoid studio exports to VRM... But that is GLB file, just change the extension. So you can import that into Blender or into Godot.

Now, sadly almost every other software wants FBX. So you could tell Blender to unpack resources so it extract the textures, set the materials the way I said for FBX (just a Base Color, a Principal BSDF and a Material Output), and export it to FBX from Blender.

Now, if you upload the model from VRoid into Mixamo, then Mixamo will rig it again. Yet, the Mixamo animation library is biased to shooters with some melee, and you might need animations that are not available there… An option for the Blender impaired like me is to animate in Cascadeur. Yet, since you want the same rig for all the animations, the workflow I would use is to first take the model to AutoCore AccuRig, which will generate a rig that both Mixamo and Cascadeur can work with directly.

Finally you will want to merge FBXs files (you will have many FBX files, each with single animations either from Mixamo or Cascadeur), you can do that in Blender. And from there you can finally get the model into Godot.

It is also possible to combine the models in Godot. In which case, I will advice use a separate project to do it (and as I said at the beginning, Godot can export to GLTF, or, since it is going from Godot to Godot you can files in Godot formats from project to project). *And in Godot 4 you can even automate the process with `tool` scripts.*

*Godot 4 has some tooling to extract animations from models into animation libraries that you can apply to another model, and also some tooling for animation retargeting. I haven't figured out a good workflow with those. Yet, you might want to explore that.*

---

I've been mentioning that you can automate parts of the process in Godot using `tool` scripts. And step up from there is making plugins, you can find some third party plugins for Godot at the [Godot asset library](https://godotengine.org/asset-library/asset). Well, an step up from making a plugin is making an application in Godot. You will find some [tools made with Godot in itch](https://itch.io/tools/tag-godot).

You might also be interested in [awesome-godot](https://github.com/godotengine/awesome-godot).

Comment: Thanks, for a lot of messages. It helps a lot, especially since you help me find something more intuitive like VRoid Studio, glb file, and Cascadeur. Before that, I use Mixamo for animations and characters, and Blender for mixing animations and exporting glb. I start learning Blender3d from scratch last week and only had a character's face done.

Comment: But, what does it mean to unpack resources, I can't import material from VRoid to Blender

Comment: @TylerChen I mean the options on File -> External Data. That is something you would need to do to be able to export to FBX while keeping the materials. You do not need to do that to get the materials from an GLB. --- I suspect you have the materials in Blender, but you don't see them because your Viewport Shading is in Solid, which is the default, and looks gray. On the top right you should find some circular icons for Wireframe, Solid, Material preview, and Rendered. Only Material Preview and Rendered show the materials. --- Please refer to Blender tutorials, I'm not a Blender expert.